# CRUD express.JS with mysql issue

Tags: node.js, express

I have this as configuration of my Express index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var router = express.Router();

 //connection database
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : 'localhost',
user     : 'root',
password : '',
database : 'learn'
});

connection.connect(function (err){
 if (err) throw err; 
    console.log('Database connected . . . \n\n');

});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var sql = 'SELECT * FROM `test`';
   connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, field){
     if (err) throw err; 
     res.render('index', {
        data: rows
      })
   });
 });

 router.get('/add', function (req, res, next){
   res.render('add_costumer', {title: 'Update'});
 });

 router.post('/add', function (req, res){

    var input = req.body;

  var data = {

    name : input.name,
    email : input.email,
    phone : input.number_phone
   };

connection.query('INSERT INTO `test` SET ?', data, function(err,rows){

    if(err) throw err;

        console.log("Error inserting : %s ",err );
        res.redirect('/');
  });

 });

 router.get('/update', function (req, res, next){
   res.render('update', {judul: 'Add'});

 });

 module.exports = router;
```

But still when I ask for req.body.something in my routes I get some error pointing Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. Here is an example of a route that uses req.body and this picture of the printing code :

[output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omEtr.png)

Any clue?

Comment: How are you calling your `/add` post?

add `console.log(req.body);` to see what Express is parsing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are requiring `body-parser` but not actually using it.

Depending on what kind of content you are accepting you should do:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // where app is your express app
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true});
```